# RoR: Elasticsearch on heroku - Faraday connection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, elasticsearch

I've run an command in terminal to seed DB on heroku:

```
heroku run rake db:seed

 and this is what happend  

rake aborted!
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - connect(2)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:82:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:21:in `block in perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:111:in `perform_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.6/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/index.rb:99:in `index'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.5/lib/searchkick/index.rb:26:in `store'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.5/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:24:in `block in store_with_instrumentation'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.5/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:23:in `store_with_instrumentation'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/searchkick-0.8.5/lib/searchkick/model.rb:80:in `reindex'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:250:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:250:in `block in conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `block in conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `block in conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:245:in `block in conditional'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_commit_callbacks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:314:in `committed!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:93:in `commit_records'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:157:in `commit'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:179:in `commit_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:198:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/app/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Anyone have any idea what should I do to resolve this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the elasticsearch config? Check if the config uses the environment variable (something like `BONSAI_URL`) for the connection.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with developing apps on heroku. Where should I look for this variable. I've run this command and the output was :

Comment: heroku config | grep BONSAI
BONSAI_URL:                   https://pe1if769:t1dfffqa1tfq7a2d@apple-4664865.us-east-1.bonsai.io

Comment: I suggest you to read this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai#using-tire-deprecated

Comment: I did what was said in the tutorial but I still have the same issue.. 
Maybe you could pin point me where should I put this BONSAI_URL to get this to work?